# ValueError: Works with IDLE timeformat error in CMD

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime-format, python-datetime

This works in IDLE but in Command Prompt Ill get this error
*"ValueError: time data 'Fri Feb 19 10:00:00 2021' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'"*

```
file_mtime = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(matfil))

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')


file_time_format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'
current_time_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'

file_tdelta = datetime.strptime(current_time, current_time_format) - datetime.strptime(file_mtime, file_time_format)

print file_tdelta.seconds

if file_tdelta.seconds < 2700:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ill changed from time.ctime to .strftime and now it works in CMD.

```
file_mtime = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(matfil)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

timeformat = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'

file_tdelta = datetime.strptime(current_time, timeformat) - datetime.strptime(file_mtime, timeformat)

print file_mtime
print current_time
print file_tdelta.seconds

#Körs bara om filens datum är nyare än 45 minuter sedan.
if file_tdelta.seconds < 2700:
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have 2 different versions of python, try calling `print(sys.version)` (or `print sys.version` if you're using 2.7) in a script under IDLE, and compare to `python --version` in Command Prompt.

Comment: Same version in IDLE and CMD (2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:30:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]).